# Is it valid to use the format email when the NameID value is a username not in the email format?

Tags: saml-2.0

Is it valid to use the format **urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress** when the NameID value is a username that is not in the email format? E.g. "foo", NOT "foo@bar.com"

Else, in such a scenario should we use **urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SAML2 Core spec, section 8.3.2:

```
urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
```

> Indicates that the content of the element is in the form of an email
>   address, specifically "addr-spec" as  defined in IETF RFC 2822 [RFC
>   2822] Section 3.4.1. An addr-spec has the form local-part@domain. Note
>   that an addr-spec has no phrase (such as a common name) before it, has
>   no comment (text surrounded  in parentheses) after it, and is not
>   surrounded by "<" and ">".

So no, you cannot use the `emailAddress` format unless the `NameId` conforms exactly to the requirements in RFC2822.

In plain English it means that if you use `emailAddress`, then the `NameId` must be a on the form of `local-part@domain`.

I think that `unspecified` is the right option to use. Then you make no promises of the format, which means that you place no restrictions on what you will be allowed to use as `NameId`.

Comment: Better might be `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent` if the ID will not change or `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient` if it's temporary.

Comment: Is the following format allowed: `mail@foo.bar.com`

Comment: @TravisSpencer Getting back to this some years later - and a lot more SAML Spec reading later. `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent` has some real tough requirements on being opaque - it may e.g. not be a username. So `unspecified` is the right option to use for a plain user name.

Comment:  @AndersAbel